# how to get the smtp authentication for incoming mail in whm cpanel

Tags: smtp, sendmail, whm

Is there any way to access the incoming mail of POP3 protocol(from gmail) in whm cpanel?
I have tried all different methods.  I couldn't find out.
Any help is appreciated ..